# Accessible 2-category of presheaves

Tags: ct.category-theory, 2-categories, accessible-categories

Let $A$ be a locally small category and let $\mathbf{Cat}$ be the 2-category of small categories, functors and natural transformations and let $Ps(A)$ be the 2-category of presheaves (the objects are functors, 1-cells are natural transformations and the 2-cells are modifications).

My question is:

Is $Ps(A)$ an accessible category?

I read some things in enriched categories and 2-categories so I think is true but I am not sure.

Somebody can help me with a references?

Comment: Presheaves of categories?

Comment: Your category of presheaves does not need to be legitimate. So, one cannot expect that is is accessible.

Comment: You can solve the issue in the comment above by either using small presheaves https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/small+presheaf (and I bet that's what you meant when you wrote the definition of $PA$), or by using class-accessible categories https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022404912000321